# How to configure nginx from http to https

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I had a Ubuntu Node.js server working with my http://www.example.com website. 
I used httpx://localhost:3000 to do my testing, then when I deployed it to Ubuntu, 
I still had to enter the port (www.example.com:3000). I was told to implement a
reverse proxy to remove the port 3000 requirement. I installed nginx and added the
following:
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
----------Delete all then Copy / Paste--------------------------

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://67.205.128.21:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

This worked, and removed the requirement to enter port 3000.
Then I found out I needed to run my app with a SSL/Certificate.
I was able to make the nginx changes to get it working as https://www.example.com:3000.
But now I need to get rid of the port 3000 requirement.
I tried the same reverse proxy setting that I used for http:, but that did not work.
How do I configure nginx to remove the port 3000 requirement.
Below is what is currently happening when I enter it in my browser:

```
http://67.205.128.21    - Works
http://example.com  - Redirects to  https://example ; Error: Redirects too many times
http://www.example.com  - Redirects to  https://example ; Error: Redirects too many times
http://example.com:3000 - Works
http://www.example.com:3000 - Works
```

Current nginx configureation:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
server_name example.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://67.205.128.21:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Then, either in the same file or a different file, add an additional server block.

```
# SSL configuration
#
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://67.205.128.21:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I think the problem was that you only had one `server` block, and so when the redirect is executed, it falls in that same server block and then redirects again.

Comment: I now get a "502 Bad Gateway". I know nothing about nginx, and just trying to following instructions from references. I think we are getting closer to the solution. How can I fix this 502? Thanks, Pat

Comment: Okay, that's progress. Is your Node.js app serving on port 3000? Check that it's running. Chances are that it's not. Look at your NGINX error log file (usually located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Comment: 2016/11/10 12:41:30 [error] 7449#7449: *42 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.200.129.120, server: mysite10.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://67.205.128.21:3000/", host: "mysite10.com"
2016/11/10 12:41:30 [error] 7449#7449: *42 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.200.129.120, server: mysite10.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://67.205.128.21:3000/favicon.ico", host: "mysite10.com", referrer: "https://mysite10.com/"

Comment: Yes, Node App serving on port 3000

Comment: If your Node.js app is on the same server as NGINX, replace your IP in the `proxy_pass` with `127.0.0.1:3000` so that it uses the loopback interface. As a side note, have you configured your SSL correctly?

Comment: Yes, on same server. I changed 127.0.0.1:3000 - same result - 503. SSL configured correctly. My site works great as long as I enter the port :3000 at the end of uri. I'm trying to get rid of having to enter the port address.

Comment: 503 is a temporary gateway failure. Have you tried it since then? Also, there are loads of questions on the Stack Exchange network that deals with `upstream prematurely closed connection` issues

Comment: Sorry it is a 502 (Bad Gateway) not 503... Hope you can still help me out.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. Changed: proxy_pass http://67.205.128.21:3000 to proxy_pass https://67.205.128.21:3000. I needed redirect 'https' and not 'http'.

Comment: Congrats on solving it. So your Node.js was expecting a secure connection then? Anyway, good luck with the rest of your project.